# Karma-dev-server missing html content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, karma-runner

I am trying to configure karma to run with webpack and react. The problem I am having is that it can not find the `<div id='app'>` in my index.html. When I look at the Karma DEBUG RUNNER it is not their and the test fails because it can not find it.

The app shows up fine when i run the `webpack-dev-server` command but not when i run `karma start`.

index.html

```
<body>
  <div id='app'></div>
  <script src="dist/dist.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/app.js'
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: './dist/dist.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon'],

        files: [
            'src/app.js',
            'test/*_test.js',
            'test/**/*_test.js'
        ],

        reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

        preprocessors: {
            'src/**/*.js': ['webpack', 'coverage'],
            'test/*_test.js': ['webpack'],
            'test/**/*_test.js': ['webpack']
        },

        webpack: {
          devtool: 'inline-source-map',
          module: {
            loaders: [{
              test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /(bower_components|node_modules)/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
              }
            }]
          }
        },

        webpackMiddleware: {
            noInfo: true
        }
    });
};
```